# Generate a more granular dataset based on a mathematical function

Tags: python, dataset, simulation, random-generation

I am looking at the following formula which models the **ideal, yearly output** of a factory:

[image: formula]

Now, the first two multipliers  are actually the *inputs x1, x2* of the equation, however we only have the theoretical yearly numbers (50000 and 0.95) for the year. I want to use this to instead of having one sample (the yearly output) to create 365 samples (the corresponding daily outputs).

From here, I now want to generate a **more practical, daily** dataset based on that equation. The naive approach would obviously be to simply divide the output into 365 samples and use those, however this not what I want.

Instead I'd like to model the **daily output** as follows:

[image: s],

where I define some lower and upper bounds for x1 and x2 instead to simulate irregularities, e.g. set the bounds for each to `[0.95, 1.05]` to imply that on some days the factory has a weaker/stronger output per x1/x2. Ideally also have a function where we have some simulated noise to make the numbers more random. In essence, summing the daily numbers (O) with this approach should then be in the same **ballpark** (mind you, not the exact same!) as the actual number written above (118,750).

I found [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/random-regression-and-classification-problem-generation-with-symbolic-expression-a4e190e37b8d) which already goes in a similar direction, but I believe is not quite what I want.

There, we have the following function, which I could use, however I am missing the ability to set lower and upper bounds (which are needed, since this factory has minimum and maximum inputs).

```
x, y = gen_regression_symbolic(m='(50000*x1*0.95*x2*(50/20))/365',n_samples=365,noise=10, 
                               noise_dist='normal', include_negatives=False)
```

I am looking to do this in Python, and would appreciate if anyone has any pointers. I feel having a modification to the above function would already do the trick, though I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Does your factory really run 365 days a year? No weekends? No holidays? What about seasonal variation?  Your method (and Nick's solution) seem to model random variation, but it seems to me that there will be much more going on.

Answer (score 0):

You could write

```
x1 = [random.uniform(0.95, 1.05) for i in range(365)]
x2 = [random.uniform(0.95, 1.05) for i in range(365)]
```

Which would give you two lists of input numbers in the desired range.

Then output could be estimated by

```
output = [50000*x1[i] * 0.95*x2[i] * 50/20 for i in range(365)]
```